# The atomic mass of an isotope from atomic weight

Tags: atoms

I'm reading for an entrance exam and have a practice question about the atomic mass of an isotope that I have to figure out. I am given the atomic weight of the element.

- How can I calculate the atomic mass of $^{138} \text{Ce}$?

I know the atomic weight which is $140.12$. I do not know the abundance of the isotope.

I tried searching but most information is about counting atomic weight.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the required exactness ? 140.12 is the atomic weight = atomic mass of Ce weighted by the isotops of a sample. Here, it's not useful ( unless missing details ! ) : 1 mole of 138 Ce = 138 g

Comment: The answer is that the atomic mass of 138 Ce is 137.906. But I have no clue how they calculated it.

Comment: precise masses of neutrons and protons and the [Mass defect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Mass_defect) explain the diff. Try this [page](http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/sc546_notes10/mass_defect.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

igael wrote the answer as a comment so I will quote him to mark my question as solved:
"precise masses of neutrons and protons and the Mass defect explain the diff. Try this [page](http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/sc546_notes10/mass_defect.html)"

Comment: But, really, you aren't 'calculating' it - you are looking it up. To calculate, in my mind, would require actually cranking through the interactions in the nucleus to get to the binding energy. Overall, I think the original exam question was horrible. (And typically, to obtain the mass deficit in the first place, you measure it by measuring the mass of the nucleus and subtracting off the number of protons and neutrons to see what is 'left').